# (R statistical package) For each value in a vector, count the number of times that value appears in a different vector

Tags: r, vector

I am attempting to get rid of all of my for loops in my R script, to speed up the runtime of my code.

I have a for loop that goes like this:

```
for(i in 1:x){
    pip$FAIL_COUNT[i] <- sum(dat$PIPE_ID == pip$ID[i])
}
```

I have a vector of IDs (`pip$ID`), which is 250k records long, with only unique values.
I have a second vector of IDs that relate to failure instances (`dat$PIPE_ID`), which is 12k records long, and contains repeats.
Not every value of `pip$ID` is represented in `dat$PIPE_ID`, but every value of `dat$PIPE_ID` is represented in `pip$ID`.

What I am trying to calculate is a third vector, `pip$FAIL_COUNT`, which records the number of times each value in `pip$ID` occurs in `dat$PIPE_ID`, which may be an integer of 0 or more.

For example:

```
pip$ID <- c(123, 234, 345, 456, 567, 678, 789, 890)
dat$PIPE_ID <- c(123, 123, 234, 789, 345, 123)
#calculation
pip$FAIL_COUNT
[3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

The for loop above achieves this perfectly.  But it is slow.
Is there any way to achieve this without using a for loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `table` on a `factor` is one way to do this. I ignored the data frame bit since we don't have the rest of the data (and your code won't run as written without first defining the data frames).

```
ID <- c(123, 234, 345, 456, 567, 678, 789, 890)
PIPE_ID <- c(123, 123, 234, 789, 345, 123)

table(factor(PIPE_ID, levels = ID))
# 123 234 345 456 567 678 789 890 
#   3   1   1   0   0   0   1   0
```

You can convert the result to `numeric` and assign it easily:

```
FAIL_COUNT = as.numeric(table(factor(PIPE_ID, levels = ID)))
```